# QwtPolar: Space between canvas and legend

Tags: qt, qwt, qwtpolar

Does anyone know how to avoid this space between the canvas and the legend?

[image]

I couldn't find where and how the legend is added to layout in QwtPolar sources. May be anyone here knows how it works?

Comment: QwtPolar calculate geometry itself.
Problem in the method QwtPolarLayout::layoutLegend.

Used bounding rect of all plot frame, legend is added to bottom side (in bottom position case).